# Is there a hit point glitch for Noel in Final Fantasy XIII-2?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

Playing Final Fantasy XIII-2 on PlayStation 3, I fought the [Long Gui](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Long_Gui_%28Final_Fantasy_XIII-2%29), and lost. I selected "retry", but chose not to fight him, again.

In my next battle, with a weaker enemy, Noel only had a critical level of HP.

Every battle since has started with the same critical level.

He can be cured with wound potion, but once the next battle begins, he is back to critical. I even tried letting him die, to use a phoenix down, but that didn't work either.

What should I do?

Comment: Dumb question, and I know it's been weeks since this happened, but have you tried to reboot the game to see if the glitch went away?

Comment: I have never had this happened when I was playing the game. On a side note, this game is now available on PC

Comment: Are you sure he doesn't have some type of item equipped that is reducing his HP?

Answer (score 4):

I believe I just ran into this issue and its solution in my play-through.

You likely have **[Bloody Medallion](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Final_Fantasy_XIII-2_accessories#Bloody_Medallion)** equipped. This item will lower your health dramatically.

Here is the description of its ability: [Exsanguination](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Final_Fantasy_XIII-2_passive_abilities#Exsanguination): *Inflicts significant wound damage to self at the start of battle.*

If you use the **Optimize** option in the equipment menu and have one or two of these items in your inventory, it will likely equip them. You can manually remove the item to fix this issue, and delete it from your inventory or manually set your equipment to prevent it from happening again.

Answer (score 0):

I would either restart or if you can go back to that point choose the harder boss. If you cannot do either then i don't think there is a solution.